# Python bottle accept data send by jquery

Tags: jquery, python, bottle

I'm using Python bottle, html/css, and Javascript to develop a website. Now in the Javascript part, I want to send a list data to the back end Python using Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/deleteauthor',
            data: keys,
            success: function() {
            for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length; i<n; ++i)
                if (checkboxes[i].checked==true) {
                    var id = "#" + checkboxes[i].value;
                    $(id).hide();
                }
            }
        });
```

In the Python bottle side, how can I receive the the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
from bottle import route, run, request
@route('/deleteauthor', method='POST')
def index():
    request.body.seek(0)
    data = request.body.read()
    #do something with data

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: for request.body, I do not get data, but some character like this: undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=.

Comment: You should just get the raw post data. can you check the update?

Comment: still undefined. When I use 'print data', it print out <StringIO.StringIO instance at XXXXX>

Comment: The data sent(keys) is a list. And I print every element in request.body.read(), it print out undefined=&

Comment: still the same. Is it related to the data I send in Jquery, as when I send a string, it works. How can I send a list?

Comment: Yes, keys should be a string. You cant send object instances over http. Who's would it be? Javascript, Python? Send keys as a string and handle them in python. Eg: js: keys = "1,4,5" python: int(i) for i in data.split(",")

Comment: Just curious--why the `seek`?

Comment: @ron.rothman: When you got the StringIO from bottle the cursor was on the last position. A subsequent read() gets nothing because there is nothing after that last point. The seek is to put the cursor back to the first position. A read() then fetches the entire content of it.

Comment: @RickyA: Thanks.  But I'm quite certain that bottle resets the cursor for you.  It's safe just to call `request.body()`, no `seek` required.

Comment: (See it for yourself: bottle.py line 1044.  Version 0.11.6.  Cheers!)